# How can I call a controller action when rendering a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a partial view for a sidebar that will show the most popular posts in my site. How can I create a separated controller for loading the model required by the partial view? (The `IEnumerable<Post>` with the popular posts)

Currently I have created a controller class that loads the popular posts but I keep getting errors when rendering the partial as I cannot call the controller and load the partial model. For example, if I call it from a view where I render a single post, the model types won't match (`Post` vs `IEnumerable<Post>`)

This is my `SidebarController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GoBaron.Front.Models;

namespace GoBaron.Front.Controllers
{
    public class SidebarController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SidebarController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> PopularPosts()
        {
            return PartialView(await _context.Posts
                .Where(p => p.IsActive == true)
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
                .Take(5)
                .ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my partial view `PopularPosts.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<GoBaron.Front.Models.Post>
@using GoBaron.Front.Data.Extensions

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="sidebar-item" id="topTrending">
        <header class="sidebar-item__header">
            <h1>Najpopularniejsze</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="sidebar-item__content">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-slug="@item.Title.ConvertToSlug()" title="@item.Title">
                    <div class="sidebar-post-item" style="background-image:url('@item.PosterUrl')">
                        <span class="sidebar-post-item__counter">+5</span>
                        <span class="sidebar-post-item__title">@item.Title</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When I want to include the popular posts sidebar, for example in the layout, I just add:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Sidebar/PopularPosts.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 40):

This is a good use case for a [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) instead of a partial view. You not only need to render a view, you also need to execute that bit of logic that loads the Popular Posts from the db.

Instead of a Controller, create a new `ViewComponent` class. This contains the logic that prepares the model for the view component in its `InvokeAsync` method, and it could take any number of parameters. In your case `InvokeAsync` takes no parameters, will load the popular posts from the db and will render the view component view:

```
public class PopularPostsViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PopularPostsViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var posts = await _context.Posts
            .Where(p => p.IsActive == true)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
            .Take(5)
            .ToListAsync();

        return View(posts);
    }
}
```

Now you need to create the view for that view component. The default view name `Default.cshtml` (as when you do `return View()` without specifying a view name) and it should be located in `Views/Shared/Components/PopularPosts/Default.cshtml`. This will basically be the same as your current partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GoBaron.Front.Models.Post>
@using GoBaron.Front.Data.Extensions

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="sidebar-item" id="topTrending">
        <header class="sidebar-item__header">
            <h1>Najpopularniejsze</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="sidebar-item__content">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-slug="@item.Title.ConvertToSlug()" title="@item.Title">
                    <div class="sidebar-post-item" style="background-image:url('@item.PosterUrl')">
                        <span class="sidebar-post-item__counter">+5</span>
                        <span class="sidebar-post-item__title">@item.Title</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Then from any other view, you would render your view component instead of a partial, passing any parameters required by `InvokeAsync`. In your case you take no parameters so it will be:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PopularPosts")
```

Finally, if you are in .Net Core 1.1 or higher, you can also invoke it as a tag helper:

```
<vc:popular-posts></vc:popular-posts>
```

PS. I wrote an [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1321/aspnet-core-clean-frontend-code) describing usages for partials, tag helpers and view components that you might find interesting.

Comment: I would like to make a web api call to get data back and display it in a section of a webpage, however I don't want this to delay loading the rest of the page. Would this solution of using the view component with invokeasync achieve this? Or is my only solution to use some kind of Javascript ,like React.js?

Comment: Why is this not accepted as answer? It seems to answer the question exactly. And it certainly helped solve my problem.

Comment: @Lasserh Because only the OP ( delavor ) can mark an answer as Accepted, and they haven't been back on SO in 4 years.